# How can I call function in drop method of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

I had some code in jquery with draggable and dropable elements.

Here is my link of jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hirenwebdp/Mf6zJ/333/

and I want to optimize this code by making one function for

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
        var self = $(this);
        self.find(".placeholder").remove();
        var productid = ui.draggable.attr("data-id");
        if (self.find("[data-id=" + productid + "]").length) return;
        $("<li></li>", {
            "text": ui.draggable.text(),
            "data-id": productid
        }).appendTo(this);
             $("#equal").hide();

        // To remove item from other shopping chart do this
        var cartid = self.closest('.shoppingCart').attr('id');
        $(".shoppingCart:not(#"+cartid+") [data-id="+productid+"]").remove();
           var isAllFilled = true;
        $(".shoppingCart").each(function(){
            if($(this).find('ol .placeholder').length > 0)
            {
                isAllFilled = false;
                return
            }
                   });
        if(isAllFilled)
        {
            $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal").html("Congratulation! You have entered each block in correct place.");
        }
```

So I had make the code but not working properly. Elements are dragged but not dropable.

After optimization the jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6zJ/486/

So how to tackle this.
Please first check both jsfiddle link so you guys can understand what problem I am facing.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you second version pass `event` and `ui` parameters

```
function test(event, ui){ ...
```

hence you need the reference of elemnt as `this` inside the function call the `test` function like this

```
drop: function(event, ui) {

    test.call(this, event, ui);

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6zJ/487/)**

Comment: @hirenpanchal whts the issue ?

Comment: its not `call.test(this,event, ui);`  , its `test.call(this,event, ui);`  :)